# Cleaning up re.search output?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have been writing a script which will recover for me CVSS3 scores when i enter a vulnerability name, i've pretty much got it working as intended except for a minor annoying detail.

```
π ~/Documents/Tools/Scripts ❯ python3 CVSS3-Grabber.py
Paste Vulnerability Name: PHP 7.2.x < 7.2.21 Multiple Vulnerabilities.
Base Score:  None
Vector:  <re.Match object; span=(27869, 27913), match='CVSS:3.0/AV:N/AC:L/PR:N/UI:R/S:U/C:L/I:N/A:H'>
Temporal Vector:  <re.Match object; span=(27986, 28008), match='CVSS:3.0/E:U/RL:O/RC:C'>
```

As can be seen the output could be much neater, i would much prefer something like this:

```
π ~/Documents/Tools/Scripts ❯ python3 CVSS3-Grabber.py
Paste Vulnerability Name: PHP 7.2.x < 7.2.21 Multiple Vulnerabilities.
Base Score:  None
Vector: CVSS:3.0/AV:N/AC:L/PR:N/UI:R/S:U/C:L/I:N/A:H
```

However i have been struggling to figure out how to get the output nicer, is there an easy part of the re module that im missing that can do this for me? or perhaps putting the output into a file first would then allow me to manipulate the text to how i need it.

Here is my code, would appreciate any feedback on how to improve as i have recently gotten back into python and scripting in general.

```
 import requests
 import re
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

 from googlesearch import search

def get_url():
    vuln = input("Paste Vulnerability Name: ") + "tenable"

    for url in search(vuln, tld='com',lang='en',num=1,start=0,stop=1,pause=2.0):
        return url


def get_scores(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    html = response.text
    cvss3_temporal_v = re.search("CVSS:3.0/E:./RL:./RC:.",html)
    cvss3_v = re.search("CVSS:3.0/AV:./AC:./PR:./UI:./S:./C:./I:./A:.",html)
    cvss3_basescore = re.search("Base Score:....",html)
    print("Base Score: ",cvss3_basescore)
    print("Vector: ",cvss3_v)
    print("Temporal Vector: ",cvss3_temporal_v)



urll = get_url()
get_scores(urll)

### IMPROVEMENTS ###


# Include the base score in output
# Tidy up output
# Vulnerability list? 
# modify to accept flags, i.e python3 CVSS3-Grabber.py -v VULNAME   ???
# State whether it is a failing issue or Action point
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't print the match object. Print the match *value*.

In Python the value is accessible through the [`.group()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.group). If there are no regex subgroups (or you want the entire match, like in this case), don't specify any arguments when you call it:

```
print("Vector: ", cvss3_v.group())
```

Comment: Cheers! exactly what was needed